# Unexpected free() behavior

Tags: c, malloc, free

I am teaching myself C. Right now I'm working on making a shell, based in part on

https://brennan.io/2015/01/16/write-a-shell-in-c/

I'm trying to add pipes like in bash and created a function called "nospace" to eliminate spaces between arguments so that strtok will then separate based on "|".

```
char* nospace(char *thestring)
{
char* returnline=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
int charpos;
charpos=0;

while(*thestring != '\0')
{
    if(*thestring!=' '){
        returnline[charpos]=*thestring;
        charpos++;
    }


    thestring++;
}

returnline[charpos]='\0';


return returnline;
}
```

Since I use malloc for the return line I was reading on SO that I need to free it somewhere so since read_args calls nospace I freed it in read_args.

```
char** read_args(char* line)
{
argamounts=0;
//tokens and strtok was taken from tutorialspoint regarding the strtok    function
char**returnargs = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*)*20);
char* token;

char* linenospace=nospace(line);

//printf("%s\n",linenospace);


token=strtok(linenospace,"|");
//printf("%s first token\n",token);
int argsub=0;

while (token!=NULL)
{
    returnargs[argsub]=token;
    //printf("%s\n",token); //test that all arguments are read
    argamounts++;
    token=strtok(NULL,"|");
    //printf("%s second token\n",token);
    argsub++;
}

//printf("%d",argamounts);
//returnargs[0]=line; //assumes only one arg for now

//cannot free memory here or returnargs is null, why?
//free(linenospace);

//printf("%s returnarg0\n", returnargs[0]);
//printf("%s returnarg1\n", returnargs[1]);
return returnargs;
}
```

But the shell wasn't reading the arguments and upon inserting all the printf's to find out where the arguments were falling through I realized that freeing "linenospace" drops my arguments. So if strtok returns a pointer which is set to token, and the "elements" of return args are token pointers, is the way that "linenospace" gets freed that I have to free the double pointer in the shell loop function?

```
void ypsh_loop(void)
{
  char *line;
  char **args;
  int status;

  do {
  printf("ypsh > ");
  line = read_line();
  args=read_args(line);
  status=shexecute(args);

  }while(status);

  free(line);
  free(args);
}
```

(I suppose I would have to change the free(args); line to free a double pointer).

---

Actually in the process of writing this question I downloaded valgrind after a quick search through SO (CentOS is my home OS) and checked for a memory leak. Sure enough there was one and changing "free(args);" to

```
int freedouble;
for(freedouble=0; freedouble<argamounts; freedouble++)
{
    free(args[freedouble]);
}

free(args);
```

where argamounts is a globally managed variable seemed to have solved the problem. I guess that answers my question but I'll post it here anyway.

---

Edit:

So apparently the loop function needs to be written this way:

```
void ypsh_loop(void)
{
  char *line;
  char **args;
  int status;

  do {
  printf("ypsh > ");
  line = read_line();
  args=read_args(line);
  status=shexecute(args);

     free(line);
     free(args[0]);
     free(args);

  }while(status);


}
```

Moving the free() statements into the do while loop as opposed to outside where they used to be makes sense because the shell keeps looping back and if I keep malloc-ing I need to free over and over.

However, for some reason if I loop through all the args and try to free them I get "Invalid free()" from valgrind. I have to free args[0] or the memory leaks, but I can only free args[0] and no more.

Adding:

```
    printf("amount of args %i\n",argamounts);
    int freedouble;
    for(freedouble=0; freedouble<argamounts; freedouble++)
    {
        printf("argument %d is %s ",freedouble,args[freedouble]);
        //free(args[freedouble]);
    }
```

into the do while loop to check if all the arguments were registered indicates that they all are, but I can't free them one by one. I'm going to edit this again once I figure out why but if anybody knows, please tell me.

Comment: I'm not sure how long you'll want to keep 'nospace()` around; spacing is very important in shells, and arguments are traditionally separated by spaces.  However, we can ignore that to deal with your 'free()` problem.

Comment: You can't call `free(linenospace)` because the split up string is being used by the pointers in `returnargs`.  When you free `linenospace`, you make all those pointers invalid.  Consider using `strdup()` to copy the arguments found so that `linenospace` is no longer in use by the time you return.  Or you'll need a more complex structure to describe the arguments.  You'll eventually need to note that `awk -F'|' '{ if ($1 > $2 || $3 > $4) print}'` doesn't contain any pipes that form a command line.

Comment: You make a very good point and I was thinking about the fact that I will have to deal with the spaces eventually. The problem is when I use strtok(line, "|") then strtok(NULL, "|") without eliminating spaces the shell just exits if I write a command like "wfile | shexit" whereas "wfile|shexit" works (the only two working commands in my shell are a writefile command and shell exit command). I wanted to copy as little of Mr. Brennan's code as possible so I can learn. How would I make a command like "wfile | shexit" work without eliminating spaces first? I'm going to think about that today.

Comment: It's probably best not to use `strtok` to parse the input, since `strtok` overwrites the first delimiter it finds with a NUL character. So when you have multiple delimiters to look for (e.g. space, pipe `|`, input `<` and output `>` redirect), `strtok` won't be useful, because there won't be any way to determine which delimiter it found.

Comment: BTW, you're not supposed to cast `malloc()`.

Comment: Your `free`s have to match up with your `malloc`s, one `free` per `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

> However, for some reason if I loop through all the args and try to free them I get "Invalid free()" from valgrind. I have to free args[0] or the memory leaks, but I can only free args[0] and no more.

You can't free `args[1]` etc. since you haven't malloc'ed them. Concerning `args[0]`, you also haven't exactly malloc'ed it, but `args[0]` points to the first token in the memory space allocated by `linenospace=nospace(line)`, usually at its beginning (unless the line starts with `|`), thus you can mostly abuse `args[0]` to free the memory allocated by `nospace(line)`.

However, `nospace(line)` is useless, since a command with all spaces removed, i. e. all arguments concatenated, is unrecognizable (unless there are no arguments). So, I recommend removing `nospace()` entirely from your program; then there would be also no additional memory allocation to worry about.